# How to Stacking ML models correctly - Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I need some help to understand how to build the stack correctly.
I started building a Stack right now from only two models: RandomForestRegressor, XGBRegressor.
Each model is essentially an independent object.
But it is also possible to create a Stack object that consists of several objects.
I can't quite understand how to combine the x_train, y_train ... that returns from each object and run the third model (the stack).
I would be happy for an explanation and even to write the function (stack_predict) for me correctly once I understand how it works correctly.

```
class ModelWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, clf,params=None, stack = False ,model_name=None):
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.x_train, self.x_test, self.y_train, self.y_test , self.x_train_scaled , self.x_test_scaled = data_perp()
        self.param = params
        self.clf = clf(**params)
        
        if not stack:
            self.train()
            self.y_pred = None
            self.predict()
            self.mae = None
            self.r2 = None
            self.evaluate_model()

    def train(self):
        self.clf.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train)

    def predict(self):
        reg = self.clf.fit(self.x_train_scaled, self.y_train)
        self.y_pred = reg.predict(self.x_test_scaled)
        
    def evaluate_model(self):
        self.mae = mean_absolute_error(self.y_test,  self.y_pred)
        self.r2 = r2_score(self.y_test,self.y_pred)
        print(f"-----------\n {self.model_name}")
        print(f"r2:{self.r2}")
        print(f"r2:{self.mae}\n -----------\n")

    def stack_predict(self, base_models):
        stacked_model = StackingRegressor(
            estimators=[(f"{model.model_name}", model.clf) for model in base_models],final_estimator= self.clf)
        
   
        stacked_model.fit(self.x_train_scaled, self.y_train)
        self.y_pred = stacked_model.predict(self.x_test_scaled)
        self.evaluate_model()


forest_params= {}
xgboost_params = {}

rfw = ModelWrapper(clf = RandomForestRegressor, params = forest_params, model_name = 'RandomForestRegressor')
xgbr = ModelWrapper(clf = XGBRegressor, params = xgboost_params , model_name = "XGBRegressor")


base_models = [rfw, xgbr]
stacked_model = ModelWrapper(clf=RandomForestRegressor, params=forest_params,stack = True ,model_name='Stacked Model')
stacked_model.stack_predict(base_models)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `sklearn.ensemble.StackingRegressor`?

Comment: @user1808924 I edited the post and added StackingRegressor but I'm still doing something wrong here.

Comment: Throw away your `ModelWrapper` class and use the standard `StackingRegressor` class instead.

Comment: @user1808924 I also want the option to run each model separately, so I use the whole class.
I run the stack and get slightly less good results from each model separately (not very significant).
I would appreciate your recommendations on which final_estimator is recommended to use for the prediction of a continuous user (apartment prices). And if there is a collection of recommended stacks for this purpose.